Excel Power Query execution slow on new Excel version?
I'm facing a very strange behavior.
In Excel, Power Query, I execute the following code to get the a CSV file content from a Sharepoint site (Connector From Web').
Source = Csv.Document(Web.Contents(ParamsReferentialFolder & "/UFI.csv",[Headers=[#"Cache-Control"="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"]]),[Delimiter=";", Columns=9, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
 

You can see that I use some 'Header' options to avoid any caching.
The CSV file is big, 150 Mb.
The step created above is only stored as a connection, and then it is used in another step, to be joined with some Excel table.
Problem : I have several computers with different excel version. For the same Excel file and same power query code :

In some computers : Ryzen 5 16Go ram, Office 365 64 bits version 2208 --> It takes ~1 second to get the CSV and process the Power Query steps
On some others computers : Ryzen 7 32Go ram, Office 365 64 bits version 2405 --> It takes ~85 seconds to get the CSV

Power Query and Excel are configured in the same way on all computers.
And I have disabled the background refresh of each query.
I have clear the PQ cache on both.
So I don't understand why, with a newer version of Excel, it takes so many tries.
On the other hand, 1 second of processing for a file of 150 MB seems strange to me. It seems like it uses some cache system, but I have been forced to not use it.
Is someone faced with such kind of thing, or have some idea on how I could trace/debug what is going on?
